# Multiple Docker Containers Hosted In Nginx With URL Instead Of Subdomain

Tags: docker, nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm a noob to docker, Nginx, and devops, so go easy on me.

I've followed a few tutorials that show me how to host multiple web apps through docker containers using Nginx and subdomains. I cannot create a new A Record for this domain, so I can't use subdomains, it has to be a url. If I could create a new A Record, I found a million tutorials that show me how to host it on ProjectA.example.com but since I don't have access to create a new A Record for the domain, I need to find a way to host it on something like example.com/ProjectA. Another obstacle is only port 80 is open to the outside, so all traffic must come through port 80 and be reverse proxied to whatever port the docker container is forwarding from.

So far I have an Nginx configuration that looks something like this

```
server {  
   root /var/www/html;  
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;  
   listen 80;  
   server\_name \_;  
   location / {  
      try\_files $uri $uri/ =404;  
   }  
   location /projectA {  
      proxy\_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;  
   }  
   location /projectB {  
      proxy\_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002/;  
   }  
}
```

This works getting me to the homepage of the project. But the CSS of the website doesn't load, and whenever I click a link, it sends me to something like example.com/signup instead of `example.com/projectA/signup`. I tried making a wildcard location (`location \~ /projectA.\*`) but Nginx didn't like that. I was thinking there's probably a way I could get something like if the referring uri contains projectA, send them to `example.com/projectA$uri` but I couldn't find the documentation on the syntax.

Basically the question is, is this a good way to tackle the problem, and does anyone have a link to a tutorial or some documentation on how to do this?

Comment: so you can't change the projects, you can't change the ports, you can't change the DNS records... for real?

Comment: I can open ports, but none of them are external facing except for 80. Access to DNS records is a definite no. It's a larger organization's domain, and they were kind enough to give me a subdomain of their domain to work on, but I can't have them create a subdomain of my subdomain for every container I'm running. There will be lots of swapping out containers and subdomains, and they will not provide the administrative means to swap those records out every time something is created or deleted.

Comment: yes, but then you have to change the projects, for example you can use `<base>` tag in HTML to solve this partially

Answer (score 0):

Using a trailing slash behind location should do it:

```
location /projectA/ {  
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
```

leads /projectA/whatever to http://127.0.0.1:9001/whatever

If you want to use regex to rewrite, it's something like that:

```
location ~ ^/projectA/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/$1;
```

or

```
location  /projectA/ {
    rewrite    ^/projectA/whatever/(.*)$ /whatever.php?path=$1 break;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
}
```

leads /projectA/whatever/foo to http://127.0.0.1:9001/whatever.php?path=foo